# Android - showing views using Handler Runnable

Tags: java, android, runnable

I am creating a simple splash screen for the practice app I am creating. I have a bunch of invisible images that I want to be displayed within the 5 seconds delayed I setup using Handler Runnable. This is my code so far:

```
    long secondsDelayed = 5;

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //I want to display this images in 2 second count
            ivLogoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivLogoStem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //I want to display this image in 3 second count
            ivSmLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //I want to display this image in 4 second count
            ivMedLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            //I want to display this image in 5 second count
            ivLargeLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeLeftPanel.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, (long) (secondsDelayed * 1000));
}
```

From the code I have now, the splash screen stays for 5sec which is just what I want, but all the images will showed up in 5 second count too. Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to show different images at 2 secs, 3secs, 4 secs, 5 secs, you need to have multiple such runnables posting at staggered times. Or you can use countdown timer where you can count number of ticks and do different actions.

If you want to use your approach:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //I want to display this images in 2 second count
            ivLogoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ivLogoStem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
    }, (long) (2 * 1000));

 new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  

            //I want to display this image in 3 second count
            ivSmLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 }
    }, (long) (3 * 1000));

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  

            //I want to display this image in 4 second count
            ivMedLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }, (long) (4 * 1000));

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {  

            //I want to display this image in 5 second count
            ivLargeLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeLeftPanel.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, (long) (5 * 1000));
```

Comment: How can I do this @Maddy?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)

Comment: Thanks @Maddy. It works really well. I just need to browse some more though for the proper implementation of this. Recommend something for a newbie to read?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are changing the visibility of all the images at the same time.

Instead of this you should use View animator

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewAnimator.html

Comment: Thanks @Ajit Pratap Singh! I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Thread` and `Sleep`  inside `Runnable` of the thread. Inside `Thread`, you can change UI (your image view) with `runOnUiThread` function of Activity as code below:

```
  new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000); // wait 2s
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //show hide image view here.
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                switch (step) {
                    case 1:
                        //I want to display this images in 2 second count
                        ivLogoText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ivLogoStem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        //I want to display this image in 3 second count
                        ivSmLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        //I want to display this image in 4 second count
                        ivMedLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        //I want to display this image in 5 second count
                        ivLargeLeaves.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeLeftPanel.class));
                        finish();
                        return;// there is no more step
                    case 0:
                        // TODO: do something afeter 1 second
                    default:
                }
                ++ step;
                // reserve next step
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
```